# Как построить распределение Райса в MatLab

Tags: matlab

как построить график плотности распределения Райса в Матлабе?

Answer (score 0):

Скачай отсюда (нужна регистрация) и используй функцию ricepdf:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14237-rice-rician-distribution

Пример кода:
X=0:0.001:20;

F1 = ricepdf(X, 0.5, 1);

V =4.6;
F4 = raylpdf(X,V);

plot(X,F1);
grid on;